# ¿Cómo Mostrar/Ocultar formulario según querysets de modelos relacionados, usando Usando CreateView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo el siguiente modelo y su clase `ModelForm`

```
class Referencia(models.Model):
    # Relationships
    sujeto = models.ForeignKey('Sujeto',  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    evento = models.ForeignKey('Evento', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    contrato = models.ForeignKey('Contrato', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
#
class ReferenciaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Referencia
        fields = ('sujeto', 'evento', 'contrato')
#
```

Ahora, con la siguiente vista, al ingresar a la url `/core/create-referencia`
se muestra la siguiente vista la cual me pinta 3 `select` para las entradas del formularios,
en caso de que alguno de los modelos no tenga objetos registrados, entonces el `select` contiene `'---------'`

```
class ReferenciaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Referencia
    form_class = ReferenciaForm
    template_name = "core/create.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core:referencia-list')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ReferenciaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        self.object = None
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form_title'] = "Registrar un Referencia"
        return context
```

**La duda en cuestión es:**

**Si no existen registros de los modelos `Sujeto`, `Evento`, `Contrato` ¿Cómo le digo a Django que en lugar de mostrar el formulario, muestre otra vista indicando que primerio debe registrar al menos una instancia del modelos sin instancias?**

Supongo que en algún momento obtiene los Querysets de los modelos relacionados, en caso de que uno de ello este vació, necesitaría saber cual de ellos para indicar al usuario.

**Gracias**

Comment: Hola sal_defrutas te diría que utilizaras el método dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) en el cual valides esa información y si no la tiene pues hace un redirect a la vista que tu quieras, si en cambio si tiene esa información pues en continua a los demás métodos de tu vista.

Comment: lo que yo es tener un listview donde me va a mostrar todo los datos y si no tengo nada solo me de la opcion de crear, donde me va a redirigir al createview, donde siento que la modificacion del metodo post esta de mas.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, para solucionar el problema, lo hago desde el método `get_context_data`

La función `enable_form` devuelve `True` o `False` si existen registros en el modelo correspondiente.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form_title'] = "Registrar un Referencia"
    context['add_new_message'] = []
    if not enable_form(Sujeto):
        context['void_select_field'] = True
        context['add_new_message'].append(("Necesita al menos un Sujeto registrado",
                                           reverse_lazy('core:create-sujeto')))
    if not enable_form(Evento):
        context['void_select_field'] = True
        context['add_new_message'].append(("Necesita menos un Evento registrado",
                                           reverse_lazy('core:create-evento')))
    if not enable_form(Contrato):
        context['void_select_field'] = True
        context['add_new_message'].append(("Necesita menos un contrato registrado",
                                           reverse_lazy('core:create-contrato')))
    return context
```

por lo tanto, lo primero que se hace en el template es preguntar por `void_select_field`

Si es `True`, se muestra un mensaje con `{{ message.0 }}` y un link con `{{ message.1 }}` para crear el registro correspondiente

Si `void_select_field` es `False`, se muestra el formularios para registrar una nueva instancia del modelo `Referencia`.

```
{% if void_select_field %}
  {% for message in add_new_message %}
    <div>
      {{ message.0 }}
      <br>
      <a href={{message.1}}>Registrar Ahora</a>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   ...
   <!--pintar el formulario-->
   ...
{% endif %}
```

No es muy elegante pero la idea puede servir para una propuesta mejor, que por supuesto, son bienvenidas.